# The best web login approach

Tags: spring, jsp, security, authentication

I am developing a jsp dynamic web project on eclipse.

I want to create an website with login functionality. I intend to store users' accounts and passwords in MySQL database. Of course, different users have different roles and rights to access different web pages. What is the best approach to implement it?

So far, I know these approaches:

1) Users enter accounts/passwords in login.jsp. LoginServlet then connects to MySQL database to check if it is correct. AuthenticationFilters will make sure only users with rights can access certain pages.

2) Use Role Based Authentication by declaring user roles in web.xml. I find this approach is not flexible, because I need to declare roles in advance.

3) Use HttpServletRequest's login/logout methods. I have not studied it.

Is my understanding correct? Could someone gives me some suggestions? Some clues would be very helpful!

Besides, I know that using POST alone to send passwords is not safe enough. Many websites suggest to use HTTPS connections. So if using HTTPS connections, does it affect the approach I choose to implement the login function?

Thanks!

--

Now, I know I need to use Spring. But Spring seems difficult for me... In Spring website I cant find out the link to download jar files. The user guide says I need to use Gradle or Maven, which I haven't used before, and have no idea why I need them. Besides, there are many Spring projects. Which one should I choose? Spring framework?

--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using Spring Security?  It's built for just that.  You don't need to be familiar with Spring but it may help.
Here are a couple of tutorials that use database authentication:
1: [Spring Security Authentication and Authorization Example with Database Credentials](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/spring-security-authentication-and.html)
2: [Spring Security Login Example with Database](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/spring-security-login-example-database)

Edit:
You don't have to Maven or Gradle.  You can simply add the jars to your build path and they will work.  The only projects you need to implement for the login to work is the Spring Framework and Spring Security.

To use Spring Security without Maven or Gradle:
Download the [Spring Framework](http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-4.1.6.RELEASE-dist.zip) jars, unzip them, and add them to your project and build path.  It's probably a good idea to find a hello world tutorial using Spring to get you started.  A quick Google search should turn up many results.

After you have Spring implemented in your project, download the [Spring Security](http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/security/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-security-4.0.0.RELEASE-dist.zip) jars, unzip those, and add them to your build path.  The links to the tutorials that I previously posted will get you started.  They may take a little while to go through and you may not understand exactly what is happening behind the scenes, but once you get it set up is works outstanding.  I'm also not sure if you are using xml configuration or Java config but I believe those tutorials are for xml.

Spring Security was built so that it could be added to any project and have you up and running with basic configuration in about 15 minutes.  After you get the basic login going (it will use the generic login form), you can search for how to implement your own custom login form, add permissions or restrictions to users and url patters, adding custom filters, etc.  I encourage you to spend some time learning it as it is highly flexible and customizable.

Comment: I posted another question relating to this one. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470880/spring-framework-and-spring-security-tutorials-version-4-x-x)